# Conditionally use file_put_contents based off filesize of XML file

Tags: php

I'm getting an XML response from the Amazon API

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXML($response->toXML());
```

I've tried using PHP's [filesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) function, but it is not outputting anything via echo.

```
$xml1 = simplexml_load_string($dom->saveXML());
$filesize = filesize($xml1);
```

Same with trying this

```
$filesize = filesize($dom->saveXML());
```

is not outputting a filesize.

The blank xml response I'm getting is 354 bytes, so I'm trying to do something like this

```
if ($filesize > '360') {
     $file_name = "List_".time().".xml";
     file_put_contents($file_name, $dom->saveXML());
}
```

But I'm only able to get the filesize AFTER using `file_put_contents`... as such

```
      $file_name = "ListOrders_".time().".xml";
      file_put_contents($file_name, $dom->saveXML());
      $filesize = filesize($file_name);
      echo '<br />filesize: ' . $filesize . '<br />';
```

Is there anyway to check the filesize of the XML file prior to using `file_put_contents`?

Comment: Prior to using file_put_contents, it is not an xml file and thus file manipulation/access functions will not work. Do not quote me on this but that may be your issue.

Comment: Aren't you looking for the strlen of the xml output?

Comment: @mkaatman will that be the anticipated filesize in bits?

Comment: It will be the current string length in bytes. There is no file until after file_put_contents and therefore there can't be a filesize.

Comment: @mkaatman Yes, that was the answer I was looking for `$filesize = strlen($dom->saveXML());` returns the number of bytes `354`.... now I can do my `if ($filesize > '360') {` .... `file_put_contents`

Comment: You could also do `if( strlen($dom->saveXML()) > 360 )` if it makes things more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem with [`filesize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) is that it expects a file path. Your file is not saved yet so you cannot rely on that.

`$dom->saveXML()` without a parameter returns a string of xml. Save it in a variable and check the length of the file with `strlen()` and you have your file size.

```
$strXML  = $dom->saveXML();
$filesize = strlen($strXML); 
$maxFileSize = 300;

if ($filesize < $maxFileSize){
    file_put_contents("myfile_name.xml",$strXML);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using PHP's built-in output buffering system. 
[PHP output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php)

```
ob_start();

echo $dom->saveXML();

$filesize = ob_get_length();

$currentXML = ob_get_clean(); // Return the Template

if ($filesize > '360') {
    $file_name = "List_".time().".xml";
    file_put_contents($file_name, currentXML);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your particular use, you could just use a negated or opposite version of that condition AFTER file_put_contents to check if it is below 360, and then delete the file using the `unlink` function if the condition fails.

```
$file_name = "ListOrders_".time().".xml";
file_put_contents($file_name, $dom->saveXML());
$filesize = filesize($file_name);

if($filesize < 360){
  unlink($file_name);
}
```